# Need framework/API to support filtering of tables

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please suggest some javascript framework which helps me add custom filters to the tables. I am looking for filter options similar to shopping sites which will allow me to add multiple filtering options and remove them.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: You mean something like the size of Matt Kruz: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/index.php

Comment: hope it helps: http://www.listjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Webix](http://webix.com), a HTML5 JavaScript framework that it has UI component like datatable with filter, order and custom options. See this [datatable with filtering demos](http://docs.webix.com/samples/15_datatable/03_filtering/)

Answer (score 0):

If your application is already build on some framework and you just need some JavaScript DOM Manipulation then you can go with jQuery, but if you want the entire application UI to be in JavaScript then I will recommend AngularJS.

Let me know if your need any further details.

Thanks